# Secondary router as access point extremely low speed

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, home-networking, internet-speed

I have had a spare BT Homehub 4 set up as an access point connected LAN-LAN via power line adaptor for boosting signal in my house. The main router is an ASUS DSL-AC68U. I receive download speed of roughly 20mbps from the main router and I was using the secondary router for streaming on Firestick and gaming only. However in the past few days a speedcheck has shown that the secondary router is now only giving speeds of 3mbps. I have not changed any settings that would have effected this. I have disabled DCHP on the second router before that is suggested.

Can anyone shed some light on how I can boost the speeds back up?

Also no problems with our line from BT end or at the house.

Comment: You have several components here – the Powerline link, the second router, and the second router's WiFi link. Have you tried isolating the problem to one specific component?